# Split a hash into many hashes

Tags: perl, loops, hash, splice

If I have a hash how could I "break" it/"split" it into multiple hashes containing equal number of keys?
Basically splice in arrays seems to be close to what I need (loop/slice) but that works only for arrays.
So what's the best way to do this?
*Update:*
Or a way to remove at most X number of key-values so as to simulate the splice of arrays
**Update**

```
{ foo => 1, bar => 2, bla =>3}
```

To be

```
   { foo => 1 }, { bar => 2 }, { bla => 3 }  if X = 1 
or { foo => 1, bar => 2 }, { bla => 3 }      if X = 2  
or { foo => 1, bar => 2, bla => 3 }          if X = 3
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want. On 5.20+, you can probably use the new slice syntax to simplify the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

sub split_hash {
    my ($x, $hash) = @_;
    my @hashes;
    while (%$hash) {
        my @k = keys %$hash;
        push @hashes, { map each %$hash, 1 .. $x };
        delete @{ $hash }{ keys %{ $hashes[-1] } };
    }
    return @hashes
}

print Dumper([ split_hash($_, { foo => 1,
                                bar => 2,
                                bla => 3,
                              }
            )]) for 1 .. 3;
```

Note that as written, the code deletes the original hash.

Comment: Can I loop the hash and delete elements in the loop? I thought it is wrong

Comment: @Jim: I `delete` outside the `map`.

Comment: Yes but inside the `while`

Comment: Also I don't understand this code: `delete @{ $hash }{ keys %{ $hashes[-1] } };`

Comment: @Jim: The `delete` resets the iterator. The condition just checks the hash is not empty. What do you imagine could go wrong?

Comment: Could you please explain this `delete @{ $hash }{ keys %{ $hashes[-1] } };`?

Comment: @Jim: It deletes the keys of the last created hash from the original one.

Comment: Yes but how? You make the hash to an array with `@{ $hash }`? I am sorry I am new in Perl and can't understand this code

Comment: E.g. what is the difference with this which does not work?  `my $hash = { test => 123, foo => 234, bar => 567 };
print @{$hash},"\n";
'`

Comment: :From http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html `delete() may also be used on arrays and array slices, but its behavior is less straightforward.` To be  honest I read about slices but I can't really understand this code (but it works correctly I tried it). Is there a way to rewrite it to make the code easier to understand at least for me? It is too advanced I think.

Comment: @Jim: Maybe in a step-by-step way, the code will be clearer: `my $last_added_hash = $hashes[-1];
my @to_be_deleted   = keys %$last_added_hash;
delete $hash->{$_} for @to_be_deleted;`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the solution provided by @choroba, but using splice, and doesn't modify the passed hash:

```
use Data::Dumper;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub split_hash {

    my ( $x, $hash ) = @_;

    my @keys = keys %$hash;
    my @hashes;

    while ( my @subset = splice( @keys, 0, $x ) ) {

        push @hashes, { map { $_ => $hash->{$_} } @subset };

    }

    return \@hashes;
}


print Dumper( [
        split_hash(
            $_,
            {
                foo => 1,
                bar => 2,
                bla => 3,
            } ) ] ) for 1 .. 3;
```